# How do I import rake tasks from a gem when using Sinatra?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rake, sinatra, task

I'm trying to add some basic rake tasks to the orientdb gem that will allow me to create the database, create database migrations, and migrate the database - similar to rails migrations.

When I had the rake tasks locally, I got the db:settings, db:create, and db:create_migration to work, but after I put them in the gem I can't figure out how to access them from the Sinatra application when using "rake".

I have a feeling I am either a) not organizing the files in the gem properly and/or b) not calling things properly from the Sinatra app.

The current state of my forked repository is at https://github.com/ricaurte/orientdb-jruby

I put the file for the tasks in lib/orientdb/tasks/database.rake => https://github.com/ricaurte/orientdb-jruby/blob/master/lib/orientdb/tasks/database.rake

Sinatra App Rakefile

```
APPLICATION_ROOT = File.expand_path('..', __FILE__)

require 'rake'
require 'orientdb'
#import "orientdb/tasks/database.rake"

task :environment do
  require File.expand_path(File.join(*%w[ config environment ]), File.dirname(__FILE__))
end
```

config/environment

```
require "rubygems"
require "bundler"
Bundler.setup

require 'sinatra'
require "orientdb"
```

ruby: jruby 1.6.0 (ruby 1.9.2 patchlevel 136) (2011-03-24 5f5278c) (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 1.6.0_20) [linux-amd64-java]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I figured out how to do it after 10+ hours of trying to figure it out and I had to patch Rake in the process.  I submitted this patch:
https://github.com/jimweirich/rake/pull/28

I also wrote up a blog entry that contains the patched code:
http://www.justinidea.com/2011/03/proposed-modification-to-rakes-discovery-of-tasks.html

[UPDATE]

I also found another way that doesn't require a rake patch, go figure...all I had to do was create a tasks.rb and require it inside the rakefile, but to make this work I had to make it look like this:

```
require 'rake'
require 'bundler'
Bundler.setup
require 'orientdb'
require 'orientdb/tasks'
```

I still think the rake patch is pretty cool though. :)

[UPDATE 2]

In the mean time until the pull request gets accepted by the rake team, I created a gem called alltasks that will load all of the rake tasks that the gems in your Gemfile and their dependencies contain.

https://github.com/ricaurte/alltasks

Comment: Nice, I think you deserve a self-learner badge for that. Hopefully two other people will agree with me. BTW, you're allowed to accept your own answer and I think it would be socially acceptable in this case too.

Comment: Thanks mu! I have to wait until tomorrow to accept my own answer and will do so then.